# Java Generic Return type Issue

Tags: java, generics, jvm

I am getting a very weird compilation error in the below Java code.

I have a simple interface having an API with generic return type:

```
public interface AttributeGenerator {

    <T> T generateAttribute(Record record);
}
```

I can write an implementation and this one compiles fine:

```
public class StringAttributeGenerator implements AttributeGenerator {

     @Override
     public String generateAttribute(Record record) {
          return "Test";
     }
}
```

Now, lets say, I add another parameter to the above interface.

```
public interface AttributeGenerator {

     <T> T generateAttribute(Record record, Set<Integer> indices);
}
```

And I provide another implementation as:

```
public class StringAttributeGenerator implements AttributeGenerator {

     @Override
     public String generateAttribute(Record record, Set<Integer> indices) {
         return "Test";
     }

}
```

The compilations fails and compiler complaints that:

The method does not override from its superclass.

I cannot understand why the compiler is not able to compile the second instance, and if it is not, I would like to understand why is it not possible for Java to provide user a facility to write such a code.

Comment: The first snippet code doesn't compile for me (JDK 1.8.0_60)

Comment: @Tanuki Strange! It compiles fine for me! What error do you get ?

Comment: Compiling the first snippet, I get: `Type safety: The return type String for generateAttribute(Record) from the type StringAttributeGenerator needs unchecked conversion to conform to T from the type AttributeGenerator`, but I have that set to a warning in eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK the problem is that in the first case you're actually disabling generics. This would result in `T` being coerced to `Object` in that case and due to return type covariace returning a `String` is fine. However, this should generate a warning since you're basically forcing the compiler to ignore generics and use the "traditional" way which would be equivalent to directly writing `Object generateAttribute( Record record )`.

In the second case, if you disable generics in the way I described above the signature will look like `generateAttribute(Record record, Set indices)` where the second parameter would be equivalent to `Set<Object>` and thus the signature doesn't match anymore.

Also note that while your first snippet would compile you could get runtime problems, e.g. if you did something like this:

```
AttributeGenerator unknownGenerator = new StringAttributeGenerator();

//You'd get a string and the system would try to cast to Integer, which clearly will fail
Integer iWontCompile = unknownGenerator.generateAttribute( someRecord );
```

What you could do is define `T` in the interface, e.g. like this:

```
public interface AttributeGenerator<T> {
   T generateAttribute(Record record, Set<Integer> indices);
}

public class StringAttributeGenerator implements AttributeGenerator<String> {
 @Override
  public String generateAttribute(Record record, Set<Integer> indices) {
    return "Test";
  }
}
```

Comment: I currently can't find the appropriate section in the JLS for this topic, so if someone does feel free to add it as a comment and I'll put the link into the answer.

Comment: Actually, I understand the last part, it was an experiment. But this means that if I want to lose the return type safety, I also lose the safety in the method arguments for Generics !

Comment: @bhuwansahni yes you can only get one or another. But if you want to sacrifice return type safety (which might lead to hard to track bugs) why don't you just provide a method that returns `Object` or declare the generic type in the interface and define it as `Object` in the implementation? Besides that using type inference like you do is very risky anyways since you can't directly access the inferred type in the implementation and thus you'd have to trust the caller to use the correct type.